# Windows Installer GPO - "Prohibit user installs" value is missing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-installer

The old Windows XP GPO template had three options for "Windows Installer\Prohibit user installs":

1. Allow user installs
2. Hide user installs
3. Prohibit user installs

The new Windows 7 template has only the first two options.

Is this an error or the third option "Prohibit user installs" has been abolished on Windows 7?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: [how to prevent users from installing programs in windows 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-prevent-users-from-installing-programs-in-windows-7)?

Comment: No, I am looking for preventing per-user MSI installs.